# Unqiue calendar for users - Python

Tags: python, calendar

I have created an online app, where I am creating events which are unique to each user. Currently, I am exporting these events to an ICS file and emailing to the users every month. This ICS file gets downloaded by user and imported into their respective calendar.

What I intend to do is, make this easier for the users.
I want it to be an autofeed instead of importing the ICS every month. Is there anyone who has done something like this? If yes, I would appreciate some guidance on this please.

Thank you,
Kind regards,
Shashank

Edit1:

```
S3_BUCKET = settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

tf = TimezoneFinder(in_memory=True)
cur_tz_loc = tf.timezone_at(lng=user.profile.cur_lon, lat=user.profile.cur_lat)

cal = Calendar()
cal.add('PRODID', "- + username + " " + str(datetime.now()))
cal.add('VERSION', 2.0)
cal.add('CALSCALE', "GREGORIAN")
cal.add('METHOD', "PUBLISH")
cal.add('X-WR-CALNAME', "calendar")
cal.add('X-WR-TIMEZONE', cur_tz_loc)
cal.add('TZID', cur_tz_loc)
cal.add('X-LIC-LOCATION', cur_tz_loc)

for item in calednar_events:
    event = Event()
    event.add('dtstart', item[1])
    event.add('dtend', item[2])
    event.add('summary', item[0])
    event.add('description', item[0])
    cal.add_component(event)

with open('my.ics', 'wb') as ics:
    ics.write(cal.to_ical())
```

Edit2:
Sorry, I do not want anyone to write whole code. I just asked if anyone has done something like this. And if you could put in right direction. Below link shows how to create calendar feed using PHP, but I am looking for is for Python/Django which I couldn't find.  https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-create-ical-calendar-feed-php-laravel-lumen. I looked at options of creating ICS file and saving the file to S3 bucket. To connect this to google calendar I used an option "create with URL". Unfortunately, this did not update the calednar when I updated the ICS file in S3 bucket. I used below link which is for Django, but couldn't really make it work. https://sschannak.medium.com/creating-ics-files-with-django-for-calendar-feeds-8d349b1168cf. I am new to programming etc, and not keeping records of codes I have tested. If they don't work, I delete and continue working with different codes. I will continue my search, thank you for your help anyway :). Have a great day.

Edit3:
Ok, I have managed to find my old code from github. Please find below. This code is what I used to create ical. Then upload_file is a function which uploads this file in S3. I have overwrite as True, and public as True, so the file is overwritten in S3 bucket.
When I use "Add Calendar using URL" on google calendar. It adds the events to the calendar. But when I overwrite the file with new data, it doesn't update the calendar.
I have read in this forums that it can take upto 8-12 hours. But it doesn't update even after few days. So surely I am doing something wrong somewhere. Hence, needs advise on how I can do this.
I hope this proves that I have done enough research before I came to ask for help on the platform. Would really appreciate if anyone can help/guide me in this matter.
Thank you,

PS: I have edited the bucket name to protect it.

'''

```
from django_ical import feedgenerator
from datetime import datetime

feed = feedgenerator.ICal20Feed(
    title="My Events",
    link="https://*****app.s3.******.amazonaws.com/shashank.ical",
    description="A iCalendar feed of my events.",
    language="en",
    )
feed.add_item(
    title="Hello",
    link="https://*****app.s3.******.amazonaws.com/",
    description="Testing.",
    start_datetime=datetime(2021, 5, 18, 13, 00),
    end_datetime=datetime(2021, 5, 18, 15, 00),
    )

fp = open('test.ical', 'wb')
feed.write(fp, 'utf-8')
fp.close()

upload_file("test.ical", "shashankapp", "shashank.ical")
```

'''

Comment: Most calendar application allow the user to subscribe to an iCal resource directly via HTTP.

Comment: Could you please point me in a direction how I can create iCal for each user in Django/Heroku. I have searched but I couldn't managed to make it work. I have looked at S3 AWS bucket option, but that didn't work either. I would be really grateful for your help.

Comment: *"…but I couldn't managed to make it work."* Show us your code!

Comment: Please see updated code. This is what I am using to create ICS file. Unforunately, overwritten the S3 AWS save lines because it didn't work for me.

Comment: All I am trying to do is for user to connect their calendar once, and I can add or remove events automatically, instead of them importing files every time.

Comment: Your code does not show anything that goes into the direction of your question.What do you expect from us as an answer? We will not write the whole solution for you. Please have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3929826 !

Comment: @KlausD. I have updated my post with the details (Edit3) you requested. I hope this might help you answer my question. Thank you in advance.